# Finding string in between brackets in bash

Tags: bash

Following is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Enter a website name here : "
read name #reads the user input
echo "Website name entered : $name"
echo "$name"

traceroute -I $name 

read -t lines < <(traceroute -I $name) 

N=0 # loop to convert the output of "traceroute" into array
for i in $(traceroute -I $name); 
do
      myarray[$N]="$i"
      echo "$N = $i"     
  let "N= $N + 1"
done

echo "${#myarray[@]}" #echoes length of array

echo "The connections made include's the following IP Addresses : "

for ((i=2; i < ${#myarray[@]} ; i=$i+9));
do
    echo $str | cut -d "(" -f5 | cut -d ")" -f1
    echo ${myarray[${i}]}

done
```

I have been trying to use the last loop in the bash script to echo output of text in between brackets of the traceroute command. For example, if the traceroute output is:

```
ip4.gtt.net (173.205.40.26)  132.149 ms  129.899 ms  129.892 ms
```

I want the loop to only echo text in between the brackets. Therefore, 173.205.40.26

I am not sure what to use. I have been looking at regular expressions in bash but didn't find anything too useful.

Comment: You could have simplified your question into:
Input: `ip4.gtt.net (173.205.40.26)  132.149 ms  129.899 ms  129.892 ms`  
Desired output: `173.205.40.26`
What I tried: `echo $str | cut -d "(" -f5 | cut -d ")" -f1`

Comment: The `nsregularexpression` tag makes no sense here -- that's a construct in the Swift language, not bash.

Answer (score 1):

This puzzle has multiple answers. First one is what you did yourself, only use `-f2` instead of `-f5`:

```
str='ip4.gtt.net (173.205.40.26)  132.149 ms  129.899 ms  129.892 ms'
echo "$str" | cut -d "(" -f2| cut -d ")" -f1
173.205.40.26
```

Or using `sed`:

```
echo "$str" | sed 's/.*(//;s/).*//'
```

`sed` here has two parts, separated by the `;`. The first part substitutes all characters `.*`  and the opening parentheses `(` by an empty string, resulting in `173.205.40.26)  132.149 ms  129.899 ms  129.892 ms`; the second part replaces the closing parentheses `)` and all characters that follow  `.*` with an empty string, resulting in  `173.205.40.26`.

Or completely in `bash`:

```
str2=${str//*(/}
str3=${str2//)*/}
echo $str3
```

Comment: Should probably replace the `echo $str` with `echo "$str"` in the `sed` case. `traceroute` can sometimes have whitespace-surrounded `*`s in its output; you don't want them replaced with lists of filenames (particularly if any names in the current directory contain parens!)

Answer (score 1):

Like @LjmDullaart, I found different solutions too. 
The `cut` command is straight forward, I had the same solution:

```
echo "${str}" | cut -d "(" -f2 | cut -d ")" -f1
```

For `sed` my solution (remember the part between the `()` and recall it with `\1`) gets a little confusing: `()` is also used by `sed`.

```
echo "${str}" | sed 's/.*(\(.*\)).*/\1/'
# or with the -r flag
echo "${str}" | sed -r 's/.*\((.*)\).*/\1/'
```

A third way is looking for an IP-address

```
echo "${str}" | grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}"
```

EDIT:
A dot is a wildcard, so it is better to use

```
grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}"
```

The first form finds `129.899`. This string matches `[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}.[0-9]{1}`.

EDIT 2:
Less ambiguous (Tx @CharlesDuffy for the comment) is

```
grep -Eo "[0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}[.][0-9]{1,3}"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer! I was just wondering if there is any way of working around the third way resulting in network speeds and IP's rather than only IP's. Therefore, if I have a icmp packet taking <100ms the third way will also output those because their beginning seems like an IP. What do you think I can do to solve this?

Comment: I'd suggest `[.]` rather than `\.` -- less ambiguous; there are quoting contexts where the backslash could be treated as part of the local string syntax rather than a literal, whereas the square brackets don't go anywhere no matter *what* kind of quoting context you're in (with the sole exception of completely unquoted use where they could be interpreted as part of a glob expression matching a file with a literal `.` in its name).

Answer (score 0):

Use `negative lookback` in `GNU grep`.

```
$ str='ip4.gtt.net (173.205.40.26)  132.149 ms  129.899 ms  129.892 ms'
$ grep -o -P '(?<=\().*(?=\))' <<<"${str}"
173.205.40.26
```

To match exactly an IPv4 IP,

```
grep -o -P '(?<=\()[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}(?=\))' <<<"${str}"
```

Here is an example of getting the entire stack of IPs in the connection.

```
#!/bin/bash
traceroute -I example.com > connFile
grep -o -P '(?<=\()[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}.[0-9]{1,3}(?=\))' connFile
```

Comment: That's a lot of nonportability for no particularly good reason. We know the OP is on a platform with bash; we don't know they have GNU `grep`, much less a GNU grep compiled with (optional, `libpcre`-dependency-adding) PCRE support.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I added a note about `GNU grep`, thanks for being vigilant. :-)

Comment: Hmm. Is there a reason to call `grep` once per line, rather than moving it into the process substitution and having the `while read` iterate over its output?

Comment: I'd also expect piping directly from the traceroute into the `grep` to work.

Comment: I don't know about that. `traceroute` is expensive and OP might want to save it for later analysis.

Comment: Sure, though I'd call that a reason to `tee` output away from the pipeline to whatever log sink -- that way you don't wait for the traceroute to completely finish before you start `grep` at all, and so can start seeing results as they become available (so long as the local traceroute doesn't buffer its stdout).

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use a regex, use bash's built-in support:

```
# our regular expression, in POSIX ERE form
re='[(](.*)[)]'

# our string to test
str='ip4.gtt.net (173.205.40.26)  132.149 ms  129.899 ms  129.892 ms'

# if the string matches the regex, print the first (only) match group
[[ $str =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

properly emits:

```
173.205.40.26
```

---

To do this properly in a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001) loop would look like:

```
re='[(](.*)[)]'

while IFS= read -r str; do
    [[ $str =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
done < <(traceroute -I "$name")
```

Comment: How is this efficient ? This requires one to loop over each line from a file or from `traceroute` output.

Comment: @iamauser, it's efficient if one loops with internal bash constructs, not starting an external command such as `grep` per line. These are relative things -- if you were processing thousands of lines you'd be better off with one `grep` processing all of them, but with only a few tens of lines (as is the case for your typical `traceroute`), it's cheaper to use a [BashFAQ #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001)-style loop and avoid paying the costs for `grep`'s startup even once.

Comment: hmm, strange that an `echo && [[ ... ]]` match in a `while loop` for let's say 30 lines (30 hops of `trceroute`),  would be faster than a `grep traceroute_outputfile`. need a `time` analysis.

Comment: @iamauser, how is it strange? `echo` is built into the shell; so is `[[`. Invoking them is just calling a C function from a C program. `grep` is an external command -- it requires a `fork()` to create a new process tree entry for it, and then an `exec()` after which `ld` is called to pull in the dynamic libraries it's linked to. There's a *lot* of overhead involved in running an external command -- we're typically talking tens of microseconds.

Comment: @iamauser, ...so, on my current platform, `time { for ((i=0; i<30; i++)); do [[ $str =~ $re ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}" ; done; } >/dev/null` takes 0.002s wall-clock -- for, again, 30 lines. `time grep a </dev/null` takes 0.014s wall-clock -- 7x longer just to start grep with no input at all and let it exit than to run 30 searches in native bash.

Comment: @iamauser, ...to measure the time needed for the `read`, while factoring out considerations outside the shell's control, consider: `exec 3< <(seq 31); read _ <&3; time while IFS= read -r str; do :; done <&3` -- I again measure that at 0.002s, once again far faster than the cost to start up `grep` even if that copy of `grep` is asked to do nothing but immediately exit.

Comment: super... It’s counter intuitive until one thinks about ‘fork()’...  thanks for a nice explanation :-)